# ImportError: cannot import name 'upath' django 3

Tags: python, django

How should I resolve the import error?

The example code:

```
from django.utils._os import upath

dirs = [upath(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(d))) for d in dirs]
```

- Django 3.2

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.0/

> django.utils._os.upath() and npath() - These functions do nothing on Python 3.

So, it looks like we can just remove the usage.

```
dirs = [os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(d)) for d in dirs]
```